# Query para retornar o primeiro registro com valores específicos

Tags: sql

Tenho que realizar uma busca dos primeiros registros com determinado valor, deixa eu exemplificar.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender LIKE '%M%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender LIKE '%F%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Isso me retorna o último homem e a última mulher que se cadastraram.

Alguém sabe como eu poderia unificar essas queries?
É porque esse é só um exemplo, no meu sistema vou precisar fazer umas 7 dessas, então se desse pra unificar seria melhor.

Estou utilizando o Laravel, se for possível fazer isso utilizando o Eloquent seria melhor ainda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo existem duas formas de fazer isso. Assim

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender LIKE '%M%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
union all
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender LIKE '%F%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Ou assim:

```
select * 
  from users u 
 inner join (select gender, max(id) id FROM users group by gender) a 
    on u.id = a.id ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma bem simples de você unificar é fazendo desta forma

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender LIKE '%M%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender LIKE '%F%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Com a unificação das duas querys acredito que possa dar algum problema em seus métodos que utilizam o retorno deste Script, pois agora serão retornados dois registros, então você terá que fazer algumas modificações em seu fonte.

Você pode ler um pouco sobre UNIONs [aqui neste site](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all/37457)

**O que é o UNION?**

> O operador UNION combina os resultados de duas ou mais queries em um
>   único result set, retornando todas as linhas pertencentes a todas as
>   queries envolvidas na execução. Para utilizar o UNION, o número e a
>   ordem das colunas precisam ser idênticos em todas as queries e os data.
>   Por default, executa o equivalente a um SELECT DISTINCT no result set
>   final, para remover as linhas duplicadas

**Para que serve o UNION ALL?**

> O operador UNION ALL tem a mesma funcionalidade do UNION, porém, não
>   executa o SELECT DISTINCT no result set final e apresenta todas as
>   linhas, inclusive as linhas duplicadas.